# How do I mail the error context? (Make a string of it)

Tags: php

Consider the custom error function:

```
function customError($errNumber, $errString, $errFile, $errLine, $errContext)
```

The `$errContext` provides a lot of useful information to debug with. How can I put this into a string and mail it?

**My first attempt:**

```
$mailContent = "Error \n";

foreach($errContext as $errType => $stringOrArray)
{
    $mailContent .= "\n$errType =>";

    if(is_array($stringOrArray))
    {
        $mailContent .= " Array\n";

        foreach($stringOrArray as $key => $value)
        {
            $mailContent .= "\n            $key => $value"; 
        }

        $mailContent .= "\n";
    }

    else

        $mailContent .= " $stringOrArray";

}
```

- This does not work with objects (yet).
- This is not very elegant.

Is there an easy way that I do not know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply:

```
$mailContent = "Error:\n".print_r($errContext, TRUE);
```

If you supply `TRUE` as the second argument to [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), it returns the output as a string instead of writing it to the output buffer.